# Difference between Scale up and Scale out App Service plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

Actually I am getting System.OutOfMemoryException for blob trigger azure function.Do i need to scale up or Scale out App Service Plan to fix this problem.

What is the difference between these two?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your original question, if your function is running on consumption plan, Scale up App Service Plan of your Azure service.The plan you already have less Memory and if you have multiple functions running in App Service Plan then scale out.

From the [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/scaling-up-and-scaling-out-in-windows-azure-web-sites/),

**Scale up means :**

> A scale up operation is the Azure Web Sites cloud equivalent of moving
> your non-cloud web site to a bigger physical server.   So, scale up
> operations are useful to consider when your site is hitting a quota,
> signaling that you are outgrowing your existing mode or options.  In
> addition, scaling up can be done on virtually any site without
> worrying about the implications of multi-instances data consistency.
> Two  examples of scale up operations in Windows Azure Web Sites are:

**Scale Out means:**

> A scale out operation is the equivalent of creating multiple copies of
> your web site and adding a load balancer to distribute the demand
> between them. When you scale out a web site in Windows Azure Web Sites
> there is no need to configure load balancing separately since this is
> already provided by the platform.

Digram depicting the difference between the two :

[image]

Comment: but i my case, as I am getting System.OutOfMemoryException for blob trigger. Do I need to ScaleUp or Scale Out?

Comment: try changing your platform target to x64

Comment: how can i do this, could you please share any article for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726350/how-to-change-azure-app-service-to-64-bit

Comment: Helpful diagrams, but the Scale Up diagram shows the situation before and after scaling, wheras the Scale Out diagram only shows the situation after.

Answer (score 8):

You need to scale up your app service plan.

"**Scale up**" means upgrade the capacity of the host where the app is hosted. Ex: Increase the memory from 1.75GB to 3.5GB.

"**Scale out**" means upgrade the capacity of the app by increasing the number of host instances.

Answer (score 4):

You scale up the **HARDWARE** or scale out **INSTANCES**

[image: Scale up or out]

Answer (score 1):

In Short **Scale Up** is vertical scaling, where you add more resources to increase capacity of the underlaying Hardware/Infrastructure.

Where, **Scale Out** is horizontal scaling, where you add more instance of the same app to process/handle request simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose Scale Out, you will get more VMs and balance your workloads to those VMs. If you choose Scale Up, your VM will get more punch to handle current workloads. More VMs or more power to your current VM