# How to switch azure app service to 64 bit mode

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, cloud

I set the azure app service to 64-bit mode:

[image]

, but then I run dotnet --info within the app service and it turns out that the system is under **x86 (32 bit)**

[image]

**Q:** So I wonder how can I switch the app service to 64-bit mode (win10-64x)?

**P.s** I've tried suggestion from [How to change Azure App Service to 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726350/how-to-change-azure-app-service-to-64-bit), but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Usually `dotnet --info` is used to view the installed version of dotnet, because it is a sandbox factor, it is estimated that after switching the platform version, the `process` version is modified.

Comment: I just updated the latest answer, you can follow my steps to verify. ^-^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the windows systems of our webapp sandbox environment are all 64bit. The option to switch in the portal is modified to process.

[image]

We can use

```
set pro
```

to check process is 64bit or 32bit.

**After change platform on portal, it will take effect immediately.**

*1. Change to 32bit.*

[image]

*2. Change to 64bit.*

[image]

You also can check `Env` on kudu site. It will change `64 bit process`.

[image]

Comment: Having the same problem. But my dropdown shows 32bit and is greyed out. Do you need a certain subscription level to be able to change it? I ran 'set pro' in the console and it appears to be on 64 bit....

Comment: I guess so. A tooltip above my dropdown says: "64-bit configuration requires a basic or higher App Service plan" (mine currently is "F1: Free").